# Risky to purge multiple workspaces in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

If workspaces are owned by the project collection service account on TFS, are there any risks of deleting them? There was a bug in a custom TFS Build script that caused workspaces with checkouts to stay on the server, and not sure if deleting those will cause any breaking errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install tfs sidekicks and you can the delete them cleanly. Roll back any checkouts and then delete the workspaces. 
The build server will create loads of workspaces over time so it's worth housekeeping monthly / bimonthly depending on your build loads.

Comment: Awesome, love the fast answer. If there aren't any pending changes still sitting on the workspaces, there isn't anything important that deleting the workspace will remove, correct? Thanks!

Comment: Yes and done cleanly. If developers leave you can tidy up in the same way. Brilliant tool that should be in every tfs administrator's toolbox

Answer (score 0):

You can undo the checkouts and delete the workspaces. I don't think it will cause any breaking issues.